# UIImage gets distorted/wrong size in UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, xcode8, aspect-ratio

I have two `UIImageView` with dimension 64 x 16 and two images (@2x):

- `image1` (128 x 32)
- `image2` (80 x 32).

I've placed `image1` in `imageview1` and `image2` in `imageview2`.

When I run the app, `imageview1` looks ok, but `imageview2` looks distorted. How to deal with different image sizes? I want the `UIImageView` size to be fixed (64 x 32).

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: set imageview's content mode to aspectFit - UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> image1 with dimension 128 x 32 and image2 with dimension 80 x 32

Your **2x** image should have **160 x 64**,  not 128 x 32.

Edit:

If you have a 64x16 **points** of UIImageView, that results in 128 x 32 **pixels** on a 2x scale screen, if you have an image with 80 x 32 pixels, that will get disorted if you try to put it inside a 64x16 point (128x32 pixels) UIImageView

Comment: Your 2x image should have 160 x 64 - How this is calculated? Suppose i have (2x) as 128x32, (3x) as 192x48 and (4x) as 256x64. What should be the UIImageView's dimension?

Comment: @user3310076 Your UIImageView dimension will ALWAYS be calculated in points. Points are different from pixels. Depending on what screen scale you have. If you have a 10x10 UIImageView in points. Your Image pixels should be 20x20 in 2x, and 30x30 in 3x . If your original image in 1x is 10x10 PIXELS, your 2x should be 20x20 PIXELS, and 3x should be 30x30 . etc. please mark as solved if this helps you :)

Comment: Yeah, I know the dimension of the UIImageView is calculated in points and the image in pixels. Indeed your answer helps. Thanks !

Comment: @user3310076 Glad to help!